# Accessibility volatile variables

Tags: c#

When I declare some variable with the `volatile` keyword, is it now utterly thread-safe, or should I still in some cases access it via `Interlocked` class or `lock` statement?

Comment: `volatile` just prevents some kind of optimizations https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx "...Fields that are declared volatile are not subject to compiler optimizations that assume access by a single thread..."; `volatile` is not a silver bullet and you have to "...still in some cases access it via Interlocked class or lock statement"

Answer (score 2):

The `volatile` keyword just inserts a full [memory barrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier) — guarantees that all read-write instructions on the CPU's pipeline are completed. For the end-user the visibility in other threads is guaranteed because when a write is done, the result is pushed to the CPU's cache (and to the RAM if needed). You should not care about this while running the app on latests Intel CPUs — they guarantee barriers on reads and writes without additional explicit instructions.

The `Interlocked` on the other hand locks the CPU bus by given memory address and allows you to perform an atomic operation on a variable, so no other CPU core can perform other read-write operation by the same memory address at the same time. Those atomic operations are actually instructions of let's say x86 CPU architecture family, so that's why you have a limited amount of operations: add, increment, decrement, exchange, compare-exchange.

Both `volatile` and `Interlocked` are related to CPU features, but common synchronization primitives - critical section, spin lock, mutex, semaphore, auto/manual reset event - are built on top of that.